# Logging Python. How to set module name in NullHandler

Tags: logging, python-3.6

I am writing a backup program with several modules. In each of these modules there are several classes with some debug and info messages. one of these modules is called logger.py which is responsible for creating the logger object with the StreamHandler, RotateHandler and FileHandler, while in the other modules I have inserted a NullHandler. The aim is to be able to import the logger into the main.py file that runs the program and have a single log file. Here my project folder structure simplified:

```
├── modules
│      ├── __init__.py
│      ├── module1.py
│      ├── module2.py
│      ├── module3.py
│      ├── logger.py
|
└── main.py
```

Here is the code of `logger.py`:

```
def logger():
    log_name = mypath/mylog.log
    log = logging.getLogger()
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(name)s][%(levelname)s]%(funcName)20s =>%(message)s")
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_name)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    log.addHandler(file_handler)

...... other handlers......


return log
```

in `module1`, `module2`, `module3` at the beginning of the file I wrote:

```
import logging.handlers

log = logging.getLogger('module_name')
null_handler = logging.NullHandler()
log.addHandler(null_handler)
```

in `main.py` :

```
from modules import logger

log = logger()
log.dubug("Some messages..")
log.info("other messages..")
```

Now this works fine except for the module' s name which exits as root in the output while I would like it to exit with the name of the module running at that time. The strange thing is that the output of `module1.py` comes as I wish while the others not.

Here an exemple:

```
[module1][DEBUG]  myfunction =>   message in module1
[root][DEBUG]  <module>     =>    message in main
[root][DEBUG]  <module>     =>    message in main
[root][INFO]   <module>     =>    message in module2
[root][DEBUG]  <module>     =>    message in module3
```

setting `__name__`   in   `log = logging.getLogger()` didn' t change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and a lot of test i found the solution.
In order to have the module name in the log output you can 2 ways:

**Set log as a class property**

```
import logging.handlers

log = logging.getLogger('module_name')
null_handler = logging.NullHandler()
log.addHandler(null_handler)

class MyClass:
    self.log = log
```

and then for each log message inside the class:

```
self.log.debug("This will have custome logger name!!")
```

output when you run `main.py`:

```
[module_name][DEBUG]  <module>     =>    This will have custom logger name!!
```

**Set log as a class variable**

this solution is even better as it is more flexible. You can have custom logger name for each class in the same module.

```
import logging.handlers

class Class1:

    log = logging.getLogger('class1')
    null_handler = logging.NullHandler()
    log.addHandler(null_handler)

self.log.debug("Im in Class1")

class Class2:
    log = logging.getLogger('class2')
    null_handler = logging.NullHandler()
    log.addHandler(null_handler)

self.log.debug("Im in Class2")
```

output:

```
[class1][DEBUG]  <module>     =>    Im in Class1
[class2][DEBUG]  <module>     =>    Im in Class2
```